# Ionic livereload continuous caching issue?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been working on quite a few projects in IONIC and many a time while I'm serving on the browser I get errors which I fixed quite a time ago.

For example, just now I got this error:

```
A tuple type element list cannot be empty.
```

Which I fixed by assigning my variable type any.But after some time I got the same error while I had already made quite a lot of changes and that error is already fixed.

So in a way, my project was in an older state.So to fix it I had to run `ionic serve` again.But I can't be doing this again and again as it's time-consuming.Many a time such conditions are quite fatal as sometimes it skips from my mind that it could be an issue due to `ionic serve` any help will be appreciated.

Comment: its a famous bug now, can track updates here :  https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/825, for now the only remedy is to restart if you see a bug that you think you fixed already.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens with me also. Suddenly I start seeing errors which I fixed quite a while back. The only solution i got was to run `ionic serve` again and again. Nothing else has helped till now.

I just recommend to keep updating the cli with a hope of issue being fixed.

With that said, with ionic 4, it will make use of the angular-cli which is more mature and you can expect issues like this to be less likely to happen. I am using ionic 4 alpha 2 with angular, and i dont see the above issue anymore.